# PDF created in android via PdfDocument is 0 bytes

Tags: android, pdf-generation

I've tried writing a simple method that takes a View from an Android Layout and converts it into a PDF using the PdfDocument class.  For some reason the resulting PDF is always 0 bytes.

Here is my code for generating the PDF.  Later in the app I'll be attaching it to an email programmatically, so I'm currently getting it as a File object:

```
public static File generate(View salesFragmentTableLayout, Context context) throws KingdomSpasException {
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(300, 300, 1).create();
        Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        salesFragmentTableLayout.draw(page.getCanvas());
        document.finishPage(page);
        File result = null;
        try {
            result = File.createTempFile("Kingdom Spas Agreement", ".pdf", context.getCacheDir());
            document.writeTo(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(result)));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new KingdomSpasException("Failed to find relevent file", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new KingdomSpasException("IO Problem occured while creatin the PDF", e);
        }
        document.close();
        return result;
    }
```

This is presently called from my unit test - I haven't got the point where I'm integrating it into the actual application.  Just in case the problem is caused by my test code I'm adding it here as well:

```
public void testGetPDFFile() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View salesAgreementLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sales_agreement_layout, null);
        View salesAgreementTableLayout = salesAgreementLayout.findViewById(R.id.salesAgreementTableLayout);
        EditText initials = (EditText) salesAgreementTableLayout.findViewById(R.id.salesExecInitials);
        initials.setText("Test Initials");
        File pdfFile = null;
        try {
            pdfFile = KingdomSpasFormsPDFGenerator.generate(salesAgreementTableLayout, getContext());
        } catch (KingdomSpasException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create the PDF file.",e);

        }
        assertNotNull(pdfFile);
        assertTrue(pdfFile.length() > 0);
    }
```

The second assertion currently fails.

For completion, here is the complete layout used in the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:kingdomspas="http://www.kingdomspas.com/android/custom"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:id="@+id/salesAgreementTableLayout">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/companyLogo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/logo_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/company_logo" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/companyAddress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/address_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/company_address" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/salesExecInitials"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/round"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="130dp"
                        android:singleLine="true" >

                        <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/sales_exec_initials" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <View
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:text="@string/submit_form"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I imagine it's simply something stupid that I'm missing or have done wrong - but I can't see it myself.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I have the same issue.

Comment: For me it was caused by running the code from a unit test. It worked when I ran it in the app itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now run this code from the app itself, rather than from a test.  The PDF is no longer 0 bytes - it is broken, but that is a different problem.

It looks like having no parent in the inflate was what caused the 0 bytes problem - I have no idea where I'd get a valid parent from at that stage in the proceedings.

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Try adding this lines and try.**

I think we need to set view width and height before drawing it into canvas.

```
    public static File generate(View salesFragmentTableLayout, Context context) throws KingdomSpasException {
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(300, 300, 1).create();
    Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

    // Try adding these lines
    // draw view on the page
    int measureWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(page.getCanvas().getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    int measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(page.getCanvas().getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    salesFragmentTableLayout.measure(measureWidth, measuredHeight);
    salesFragmentTableLayout.layout(0, 0, page.getCanvas().getWidth(), page.getCanvas().getHeight());

    salesFragmentTableLayout.draw(page.getCanvas());
    document.finishPage(page);
    File result = null;
    try {
        result = File.createTempFile("Kingdom Spas Agreement", ".pdf", context.getCacheDir());
        document.writeTo(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(result)));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new KingdomSpasException("Failed to find relevent file", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new KingdomSpasException("IO Problem occured while creatin the PDF", e);
    }
    document.close();
    return result;
}
```